# What are the exact conditions for Tarjan's SCC algorithm to work properly?

Tags: algorithm, graph

For instance, are multiple edges allowed between vertices? Or, can we have both edges from A to B and B to A? I just wonder what kind of directed graph we are talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tarjan's algorithm works with any directed graph at all.  Yes, you can have multiple vertices between edges, and both edges from A to B and B to A.  You can also have an edge from a vertex to itself, and you can have multiple disconnected subgraphs.